# can't delete This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ptbLabel.'

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I have error like this.

```
This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ptbLabel.
```

I know this error happens when there is something wrong with a linkage between storyboard and source code.

So, I deleted the linkage from storyboard.

then this error disappear.

However I reconnect again from Storyboard manually.

```
@IBOutlet weak var ptbLabel: UIImageView!
```

It shows the same error.

Why does this happen??

I guess it might be something related with project name change.

I have changed project name just a few steps before, by clicking the projectname at the top of left pain.

These are the error log below

```
] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7ff6e0404580> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ptbLabel.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110901b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001102c5141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110901a59 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010f6f1e8b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 292
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010dfe0644 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 87
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010e24d6b9 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001108a7e8d -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 269
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010e24c06f -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1856
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010dfe6c73 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010dfe7589 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010dfe78ba -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 195
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010dfe810a -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010deb063a -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 65
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010deb0d20 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 294
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010dec3b6e -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010de3d31f -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4346
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010de43584 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1709
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010de40793 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 182
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001149875f6 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    19  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011498746d -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 186
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001149877f6 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001108a7c01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011088d0cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011088c5ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011088c016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010de3f02f -[UIApplication _run] + 468
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010de450d4 UIApplicationMain + 159
    27  BeatBrain                           0x000000010be5dcb0 main + 48
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011198d65d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

-------- solution -------

I opened the storyboard as source code.

then found customModule is not changed when I changed the projectname.

```
 <viewController id="2" customClass="viewController" customModule="OldProjectName" sceneMemberID="viewController">
```

I changed here OldProjectName -> NewProjectName

it works.

thanks very much.

Comment: Please show us your `ptbLabel` declaration.

Comment: have you checked the referencing outlets in connections inspector? There might be a missing reference which is actually not in your class. And don't forget to clean project, delete derived data from library, and try again.

Comment: I have cleaned derived data. And connection looks like correct in connection inspector. I also updated the article as well

Comment: Open your storyboard in a text editor and look for misplaced `ptbLabel` references...

Comment: I solved problem and added the article how to solve. thank you very much. Opening Storyboard as source code helped me very much.